# autotools conditional linking

Tags: conditional-statements, ld, autotools

How to use different static library in ld, depending on version installed in the system ?
I need to link my program with esnacc lib which may exists as:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcxxasn1.a
```

or

```
/usr/local/lib/libc++asn1.a
```

Comment: This question is too vague, but it sounds like you want a build infrastructure that detects this. This is too broad to answer. You might want to [good tutorial](https://autotools.io/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Write an m4 macro that tries to find the right version of the library.
Set a variable use that variable to link your program against it.